# Jquery: Focus last line on textarea on change

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to focus the last line of a textarea with the id "textarealog" on textarea change. I don't get what is wrong in the script below. Your help will be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="textarea textarealog textarealogtextarea" id="textarealog" variable="#a"></textarea>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery.fn.lockCursor = function() {
    return this.each(function() { 
        if (this.setSelectionRange) { 
            var len = $(this).val().length * 2; 
            this.setSelectionRange(len, len);
        } else {
            $(this).val($(this).val()); 
       }
    });
};

$('.textarealog').on('change', function(){
    $(this).lockCursor();
});
```

JSFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/vfbhd2r9/

Comment: Please, improve your answer adding the basic HTML markup needed to simulate the issue.

Comment: I can't add the textarea html code.

Comment: Why not ?, just put a sample code, not the real code you are using if you can't show it. Example: `<textarea id="mytextarea" class="someclass"></textarea>`. But take care that is the one matching with your JS code.

Comment: I mean I past it in the original post but It don't show. Here it is here : <textarea class="textarea textarealog textarealogtextarea" id="textarealog" variable="#a"></textarea>. Note that i changed the "." to "#" a common error I do.

Comment: Ok, i have added it for you. Also, the **textarea** has the class **textarealog**, so using `$(".textarelog")` for select it will work.

Comment: True. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I've added a JsFiddle if it can help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue with a bind function:

```
$('#textarealog').bind('input propertychange', function(){
    $(this).lockCursor();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Id then you should use #, because you are passing Id and below you are getting a class. Use this might help you

```
      $("#textarealog")
```

Comment: Props for the #, I always make this error :( but the code is still not working.

Comment: for now i am on the way going to office, but you can try to search for the attr() where u will be using extra class name for accessing that value or u can use input method something like this focus(input['name of input']);